# Why doesn't this C++ code (count << NUM_COINS) compile?

Tags: c++, macos

I am a computer science student and taking my first C++ class. I have a problem understanding what is going on with my code:

```
// This program uses the address of each element in the array. 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int NUM_COINS = 5;
    int coins[NUM_COINS] = {5, 1, 25, 5, 10};
    int *p1;        // Pointer to a double.
    int count;                      // Counter variable. 

    // Use the pointer to display the values in the array. 
    cout << "Here are the values in the coins array: \n";
    for(count = 0; count << NUM_COINS; count++)
    {
        // Get the address of an array element
        p1 = &coins[count];

        // Display the contents of the element
        cout << *p1;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

1. so my first question is why doesn't make compile it? I have no problems at all with any of my other simple programs. I am using g++ on OS X 4.2.1. I have to type the g++ -o command for it to compile, if not...i get these errors:

> g++    -c -o 9-8.o 9-8.cpp cc   9-8.o 
>   -o 9-8 Undefined symbols:   "std::basic_ostream >&
>   std::operator<<
>
> > (std::basic_ostream >&, char
> >     const*)", referenced from:
> >           _main in 9-8.o
> >           _main in 9-8.o   "std::ios_base::Init::Init()",
> >     referenced from:
> >           __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in 9-8.o
> >     "std::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator >::size() const",
> >     referenced from:
> >           std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long,
> >     std::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator > const&)in 9-8.o
> >     "std::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator
> >     ::operator[](unsigned long) const", referenced from:
> >           std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long,
> >     std::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator > const&)in 9-8.o
> >           std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long,
> >     std::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator > const&)in 9-8.o
> >           std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long,
> >     std::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator > const&)in 9-8.o
> >     "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced
> >     from:
> >           std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long,
> >     std::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator > const&)in 9-8.o
> >           ___tcf_0 in 9-8.o
> >           _main in 9-8.o
> >           unsigned long const& std::min(unsigned long
> >     const&, unsigned long const&)in 9-8.o
> >           __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in 9-8.o
> >           global constructors keyed to mainin 9-8.o
> >           CIE in 9-8.o   "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()",
> >     referenced from:
> >           ___tcf_0 in 9-8.o   "std::basic_ostream >&
> >     std::endl
> >     (std::basic_ostream >&)",
> >     referenced from:
> >           _main in 9-8.o   "std::basic_ostream
> >     ::operator<<(std::basic_ostream >&
> >     (*)(std::basic_ostream >&))",
> >     referenced from:
> >           _main in 9-8.o   "std::basic_ostream
> >     ::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
> >           _main in 9-8.o   "std::cout", referenced from:
> >           _main in 9-8.o
> >           _main in 9-8.o
> >           _main in 9-8.o ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit
> >     status make: *** [9-8] Error 1

which leads to my second question. Even if I do type the g++ command, it compiles but after running it outputs an empty array. So my question #2 is: is my code correct? How do I properly use pointers with the reference address statement?

Comment: sorry for the format, I don't understand the formatting on this site

Comment: @J-e-L-Lo : Use `{}` tag present on the editor window to format the code.

Comment: the left-shift operator in place of the comparison operator is a bug, but i still dont understand why that should give you std::iostream errors. Once you fix that, the rest of the code works ok for me.

Comment: @Sriram: Yup, that error is specific to the compiler I believe.

Comment: Its funny how the g++ command runs the program fine except for displaying the string contents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Reason**: You are not using the comparision operator correctly. After changing it to be "<", your code should work correctly.

```
for(count = 0; count << NUM_COINS; count++)
                     ^ should be "<" here
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem except that one problem in your `for` loop:

```
for(count = 0; count << NUM_COINS; count++)
                   //^^
```

That is not comparison. That is left-shift operation. I'm sure you didn't intend that.

That should be : `count < NUM_COINS`.

Comment: @Nawaz: That is most definitely a bug, but funnily it compiled on my  machine. Also, should this bug result in std::iostream errors?

Comment: @Sriram: left-shift is syntactically correct. So it will compile. Also, the std::iostream errors come from somewhere else which is not the code you've quoted here.

Comment: ? what do you mean not the code. I am compiling the same exact code on my macbook pro 2010 and its giving me those errors.

Comment: @J-e-L-L-o: Are you able to compile and run any other program that uses `iostream`?

Comment: thats stupid weird...I changed the left shift operator and it was still not compiling. I saved the cpp file to a different directory and *bam* it works. Thanx guys.

Comment: @J-e-L-L-o: Are you sure your paths(to the libraries) etc. have been correctly set in the compiler? otherwise, this is very weird indeed..

Comment: @Sriram: Yes...I completely reinstalled the os and developer tools. I am on a bone stock re-install of Snow Leopard and updated to 10.6.7. But it works, I just missed a simple character.